# Map density in ggplot2 on a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a map of a portion of Chicago. I am using geom_density_2d to show density two variables.

```
ggmap(Chicago_density_map)+ geom_density2d(data = trip_locations,
         aes(x=start_lng, y=start_lat, 
             color = member_casual),
         size=1)
```

Here is the outcome.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2XFT.jpg

I want the densities to be filled in. So whichever area has the highest density will fill in the space, the lower density will be inside. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using `fill = member_casual`, instead of `color =`? Or `geom_density_2d_filled`?

Comment: @DavidClarke, if I add the `fill =member_casual`, I get the same outcome as `color =`. So I think `geom_density_2d_filled` could work, but because the density of one of the variables is much larger than the other, the whole map turns blue. Being new to all of this, am I biting off more than I can chew?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.